# Proper use of prolonged

Tags: word-choice

I have seen examples of using prolonged with negative connotations. If a relationship between two countries is cordial and last for more than five centuries is it correct to use the phrase " prolonged relationship"?

Comment: The word "prolonged" itself doesn't have any positive or negative meaning. So yes, you can use it both in positive and negative contexts.

Comment: *prolonged* does imply 'beyond **reasonable** length of time', which is inherently negative. On the other hand, *extended* is (essentially) balanced, though even that could have negative pragmatics as in a polite reminder, 'avoid extended discussions in comments, use chat instead' :) Words acquire such implications by usage and collocation.

Comment: I might go for '*enduring* relationship' though the exact meaning is now more than 'extended'. Alternatives could be *sustained*, *lasting*, *long lasting*, etc.

Comment: @Kris No doubt you are right. But the question was not "what is the best word to describe this", only "is this a correct word usage".

Answer (score 1):

Prolonged definition:

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/prolong): continuing for a long time.

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prolonged): continuing for a long time or longer than usual; lengthy.

Example usage:

1. **Prolonged** use of the drug is known to have harmful side-effects. (negative connotation)
2. With proper care **prolonged** battery life can be ensured. (Positive connotation)

Its evident that "Prolonged" is an adjective that is used to define the lengthy duration of something irrespective of the positive/negative meaning of the context.

So yes, It is correct to use "Prolonged relationship".

However, in this particular case "Prolonged" may not be the best option. As suggested by Kris, you may go for *sustained, lasting, long lasting* etc.

Answer (score 0):

As 'prolonged' simply means longer than expected, or longer than initially planned, it has no inherent negative connotations, so in this example you could use 'prolonged relationship.'

As Kris comments, though, there are some words which have a definitely positive connotations. 'Enduring,' does imply being strong enough to hold through challenge,  so it may be more appropriate here.